# The best practices for a web chat application

Tags: .net, mobile, chat

I need to create middle point application which will work like chat server for web site chat and for mobile applications as well. Could you help me with the best practices in this case?
I want to use .NET technologies for the chat server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario there are few differences in how chat would work:

1. In a website, you have the ability to push a chat application that the user can install via Java or ActiveX. In a web application, you have to upload it to a store such as Apple's AppStore
2. A phone application could interoperate over a wireless network as well as 3G and could switch on the fly which means you may need to consider "state"
3. Unless your volume is really low, you will probably need more than one server which will introduce performance/syncronization issues. If this is for commercial usage, I would recommend hiring a firm that has done this type of work before (I know of several)